# Trying to upload an image in php

Tags: php

I am trying to upload an image in PHP
I have this for an upload form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="topbar"></div>
    <h1>Client Name</h1>
    <form>
        <input type='text' name='name'></input>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Name" name="submit">
    </form>
    <h1>Client Logo</h1>
    <form action="process.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Process.php:

```
<?php
$uploaddir = "../";
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)){
  header('Location: ' . 'http://clay.dev/uploads/' . $uploadfile);
}
else{
  echo 'Failure';
}
print_r($_FILES);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

I'm trying to get the selected image to appear in a different php file between two div tags. How do I do this? Thanks

Comment: you should store the image in a certain name if you don't want to use database to store the name. then in your another php you can show the image, otherwise, that php file can't know your image filename.

Comment: you're simply assuming the upload is always performed, and always succeeds. bad idea. there's a `['error']` parameter in $_FILES for a reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this condition to complete your code properly:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])).
```

Then you can use img tag to display image in respective div

```
img src="yourLocation/yourImageName" alt="Name"
```

Directory path should be

```
$uploaddir = "..//uploads//";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your directory should be:

`$uploaddir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/';`

Or

`$uploaddir = "../uploads/";`

Answer (score 0):

You can store your image name to database when upload in PHP a. then in PHP b, read that filename to show it.

or, store the filename to a file, e.g. `data.txt`. in PHP b, read it and show it too.

or, after upload in PHP a, jump to PHP b with that filename in your url.